# how to append 4-5 spaces in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

> i am trying to append 4-5 apces by the below code but it's not
>   working. new to Jquery,JS pls help.

```
$("#<%= lbl100.ClientID %>").text("Your search request is too broad and the first 100 results are displayed.Please refine your search if your result does not show.").append("            ");
```

Note:- I have also used `&nbsp` and `adding space` in the end(not worked) but they are printing as it is and space not coming

Comment: Try with [`&nbsp`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0ahUKEwiC9PfRoJfUAhXFqY8KHYYJAmEQFghUMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fhtml%2Fhtml_entities.asp&usg=AFQjCNEPHEcANIkULXIA3Lp4Lj-eCLuPvQ&sig2=_cvGI756RhdOlJTn9pYBPQ)

Comment: tried not worked @AlivetoDie

Comment: @prasad tried not worked

Comment: @AkhilJain Are you sure. Can you add a [mcve]?

Comment: [CSS solution] How about adding some `margin-right` or `padding-right` to that element?

Comment: @AkhilJain see below `alive to die` answer is working good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&nbsp;` with `html()`and make sure that id:- `<%= lbl100.ClientID %>` is correct and exists.

Example:-

```js
$("#abc").html("Your search request is too broad and the first 100 results are displayed.Please refine your search if your result does not show.      ").append("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="abc"></div>
```

Note:- if you try to select the text then you will see that spaces are also selected.

***Another way to do it:-***

```js
$("#abc").html("Your search request is too broad and the first 100 results are displayed.Please refine your search if your result does not show.&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;see the space");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="abc"></div>
```

Note:- Make sure that jQuery library added before your script code otherwise it will not work and you will get `$ is undefined` error in your browser console.

Answer (score 1):

That's how HTML works: [white-space is collapsed](http://code.stephenmorley.org/html-and-css/white-space-handling/) into a single space. If you need hard-coded duplicate spaces you need to insert a literal [U+00A0 NO-BREAK SPACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) character. There're several ways to do it:

- Type it as-is (you may also use the clipboard)
- Insert a JavaScript entity
- Insert an HTML entity

Snippet illustrates #2 and #3 (the editor would convert the character to regular space):

```js
$("div:nth-of-type(1)").text("One\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0\u00A0Two");
$("div:nth-of-type(2)").html("One&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Two");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```